# Forma correcta de escribir "¡Ya ves!" o "¿Ya ves?"

Tags: puntuación, escritura

¿Cual es la forma correcta de escribir **Ya ves**?

Normalmente he visto que se ocupa cuando se quiere utilizar algun hecho o afirmación para mostrar un punto de vista.

Por ejemplo utilizando un frase de Gandhi como afirmacion:

> El débil jamás puede perdonar

Alguien puede utilizar la frase, para decirle a alguien

> Ya ves, necesitas aprender a perdonar para ...

Otro ejemplo es cuando un niño se cae y su madre le dice

> Ya ves, te dije que no te subieras.

Lo que no sé es cuál es la forma correcta de escribirlo o en qué casos se aplica cada forma

- ¡Ya ves! ...
- ¿Ya ves? ...
- Ya ves, ...

**Edición:** Soy de México y es común escucharla ¿Qué tan común es la frase en otros lugares?

Comment: Casi siempre sería pregunta, en mi experiencia.

Comment: In Europe, never a question. "¿Qué tan común [...]?" not used either.

Comment: Curioso, en el ejemplo del niño que se cae, yo como padre y residente en España le diría "¿Lo ves? Te dije que no te subieras."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo no hay una única forma correcta, las tres posibilidades que listas caben y, dependiendo del tono y la intención, se puede escribir:

> ***¿ya ves?, te dije que te golpearías si te subías sin cuidado***

(si se quisiera connotar un tono aleccionante)

O

> ***¡ya ves!, te dije que te golpearías ... ***

(cuando recriminando con énfasis)

También es gramaticalmente válido hacerlo sin signos (porque no es una pregunta ni tiene que transmitir una carga enfática particular)

> ***Ya ves, te dije que te golpearías...***

(haciendo una enunciación pura, sin propósitos ni interrogativos ⁠— ya sea directos o retóricos⁠—, ni exclamativos)

Por último como información adicional, leyendo un poco sobre [las reglas para los signos de interrogación y exclamación](https://clicnota.wordpress.com/2018/05/04/signos-de-interrogacion-y-exclamacion/), encuentro que hay otras posibilidades de uso, tanto que:

:: **es posible juntarlos**, al modo de

> **¡¿ya ves?!, te dije que te golpearías**

e incluso (algo que aprendo ahora)

:: **combinar el inicio de un signo y el final de otro**, para connotar ambos propósitos

> **¿Ya ves!, te dije que te golpearías**